# Округление до N знаков после запятой в с++

Tags: c++

есть число типа `double`, например `4.64452675`

Как в `С++` сделать округление до `N` знаков после запятой? Либо отсечение? Не нашел нужной функции

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
static const double powerOfTen[] = { 1.0, 10.0, 100.0, ... };

double truncated = std::trunc(d * powerOfTen[N]) / powerOfTen[N];
double rounded = std::floor(d * powerOfTen[N] + 0.5) / powerOfTen[N];
```

Comment: что означает + 0.5 ? точнее, почему именно 0.5 ?

Comment: А это же округление!

    floor(0.0 + 0.5) == 0.0
    floor(0.1 + 0.5) == 0.0
    floor(0.6 + 0.5) == 1.0

И т. д.

Answer (score 13):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath> // для round

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  double value = 4.64459675;

  // Положительные числа
  cout << round(value*10)/10 << endl; // Округление до первого знака
  cout << round(value*100)/100 << endl; // второго
  cout << round(value*1000)/1000 << endl; // третьего
  cout << round(value*10000)/10000 << endl; // четвертого

  // Отрицательные числа
  cout << round(-value*10)/10 << endl; // Округление до первого знака
  cout << round(-value*100)/100 << endl; // второго
  cout << round(-value*1000)/1000 << endl; // третьего
  cout << round(-value*10000)/10000 << endl; // четвертого


  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Результат:**

```
4.6
4.64
4.645
4.6446
-4.6
-4.64
-4.645
-4.6446
```

**Вывод**

Количество нолей равно числу знаков после запятой

Comment: round по сути нормальный вариант но все же если вбить например 3,499999...999 (15 девяток) то оно округлит до 4

Comment: А как тогда надо, чтобы решить задачу ТС?

Comment: Хм.. Да, странно. https://ideone.com/VNoDWr

Answer (score 3):

Думаю проще:

```
std::stringstream stream;
stream << std::fixed << std::setprecision(N) << d;
stream >> d;
```

Answer (score 2):

В стримах (типа `std::wstringstream`)есть такое:

---

```
std::setw(4):
wstream<<std::setw(4) //задание 4 знаков
```

---

И

```
std::hex:
wstream<< std::hex //задание хексадецимальной надписи (есть ещё научная и я не помню какая)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  double value; //число
  doudle denom; //желаемая точность
  cout<<(value-remainder(value,denom));
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double _trim_tail (
      const double& p_value
    , const int p_decimal_places = 4
    , const int p_make_round = 1
) {
    double exponent = round( log10(fabs(p_value)) );

    double res = p_value * pow(10,-exponent);

    if (fabs(res) < 1.0) {
        res = res * 10.0;
        exponent -= 1;
    } else if (fabs(res) >= 10.0) {
        res = res / 10.0;
        exponent += 1;
    }

    if (p_make_round != 0) {
        res = round(res * pow(10,p_decimal_places)) / pow(10,p_decimal_places);
    } else {
        res = trunc(res * pow(10,p_decimal_places)) / pow(10,p_decimal_places);
    }

    res = res * pow(10,exponent);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. возможно, стоит привести пример использования. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Это хорошее решение, но уверены ли вы что оно работает? В constexpr оно у меня не округляет, возвращает что-то вроде 1.000000001 например. Кажется оно должно возвращаться uint64 и pow от него вызывать тоже.

Answer (score 0):

`double x = 4.64452675; cout << setprecision(n) << fixed << x << endl; // n - кол-во знаков после запятой`