# Как увеличить double?

Tags: c++

Когда я нахожу корень на c++ он автоматически округляется,когда в java до последней цифры, как это можно убрать и потом округлить до 6 знаков. Извините за глупый вопрос я больше шарю в java. Использую с++11

```
double dist(point x, point y) {
return sqrt((x.x-y.x) * (x.x-y.x) + (x.y-y.y) * (x.y-y.y));}
```

этот метод возвращает число с 5 цифрами после запятой, хотя их больше, как мне сделать так чтобы возвращалось полное число?

Comment: [это не то?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/209649/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE-n-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%81)

Comment: @MikeV. я имел ввиду как мне увеличить double

Comment: точнее напишите в вопросе : что есть и что нужно

Comment: @MikeV. все изменил

Comment: Этот метод НЕ "возвращает число с 5 цифрами после запятой". У типа `double` вообще нет никакого фиксированного количества цифр после запятой. Очевижно, это вы сами потом печатате свое число с "с 5 цифрами после запятой", но к "этому методу" это не имеет нкакого отношения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вы **выводите** значение?
Как `cout << x`?
Но по умолчанию так **выводится** 6 знаков. У вас проблема не в том, что `double` неточный, а в том, что вы его выводите неточно.

Попробуйте, например, так:

```
cout << setprecision(12) << x;
```

Comment: а как можно с помощью printf вывести

Comment: и чтобы округлялось в меньшую степень

Comment: Например, как `printf("%.10lf\n",x);`. См. тут - http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf