# неправильный результат при qSin(180) градусов Qt / C++

Tags: c++, qt

Неправильный

```
real result = qSin(qDegreesToRadians(qreal(180)));
```

результат = 1.22465e-16 а нужен 0
и нужно чтобы было floating number а не int

Comment: вы думаете   ваш результат имеет большую разницу с нулем?  Конечно вы теряете точность  в значении Пи, конечно этот результат больше чем  numeric_limits<float>::min(), но он настоько близок к нулю, что нинакаие расчеты не повлияет отрицательно

Comment: Первое что надо усвоить при работе с плавающей точкой, что не быват точных значений, всегда надо сравнивать числа с некой заранее определенной точностью.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *qDegreesToRadian* принимает *double* или *float* - для избежания путаницы лучше использовать их
2. *qDegreesToRadian(180)* возвращает не точное значение Пи, а 3.14159, а потому результат использования *QSin* лишь приближен к 0. Оптимально после использования функции делать округление, используйте *std::round* или явное приведение *(int)*.
3. Используйте *std::sin*, поскольку *qSin* выглядит как:

   ```
   inline qreal qSin(qreal v)
   {
       using std::sin;
       return sin(v);
   }
   ```

Comment: проблема в том что мне нужна максимальное приближонное значение например sin(10) = 0.173648;  вот только при sin(180) где результат должно быть 0 мне нужно только тогда. А если использовать round то например результат sin(10) будет 0

Comment: @Artyom вы сказали что нужен int, по сему посоветовал round. Если нужно приближение, то можно как в таблицах Брадиса округлять до восьмого знака - точность не будет серьёзно потеряна, как округлять здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/209649/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE-n-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%81 Ну либо добавьте округление только для 180, 45 градусов