# Сравнение двух double в Си

Tags: c

Как правильно сделать сравнение, чтобы только до 7 знаков после запятой (включительно). То есть если 8й знак различается, то сравнение все равно проходит.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define  eps 0.00000001
int main()
{
    double first = 1.123123399;
    double second = 1.1231234;
    if (fabs(first - second) > eps) {
        printf("ne ravno\n");
    } else {
        printf("ravno\n");
    }
    first = 1.1231233;
    if (fabs(first - second) > eps) {
        printf("ne ravno\n");
    } else {
        printf("ravno\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Ну как советуют, делаю через маленькое значение. Но вот если 7й знак будет отличаться на единичку, а за тем, который меньше, будут следовать куча девяток, то сравнение пройдёт.

Comment: Округлиь и перевести в строку. Потом сравнивать строки

Comment: Попытался. Каким образом тогда в строку превращать? snprintf число 1.123123399 делает в строке 1.1231234

Comment: Анадо какое число получить? Умножте число на pow(10,7)  и привидите к int и уже int сравнивайте

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/209649/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE-n-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%81

Comment: У вас в eps единичка в 8-м разряде

Comment: Вообще-то обычно смотрят на разность двух чисел, а не на конкретную цифру... Если сравнивать числа порядка ста тысяч, то все равно нужен восьмой знак *после запятой*?

Comment: Скорее всего вы упираетесь уже в предел точности самого типа данных. И всё же лучше проиллюстрируйте что вы имели в виду под фразой: "Но вот если 7й знак будет отличаться на единичку, а за тем, который меньше, будут следовать куча девяток, то сравнение пройдёт." - приведите пример таких чисел, что на них выдаёт ваш код и что вы хотели бы получить.

Comment: Подумайте об этом вот как: изображение числа в виде строки из чисел - случайность. Числа могут быть записаны в разных системах счисления. То что важно - величина чисел и разница между ними. Ваш цифровой критерий может поменяться если к обоим числам прибавить одинаковое небольшое слагаемое. Вы уверены, что такая чувствительность - хорошая вещь? Думаю, что критерий "два числа близки" должен базироваться на их алгебраических свойствах. А сколько девяток в записи после запятой - дело десятое.

Answer (score 2):

> чтобы только до 7 знаков после запятой

1. Умножаете на 10000000
2. Округляете или обрезаете (тут уж вам выбирать как)
3. Записываете результат в int
4. Сравниваете intы